# Change the color of an html 5 output object based on value

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to change the color of the result of a calculation to red if it is negative. I tried a style sheet, and putting the output into a javascript call, but it did not seem to work. Is there a way to change the color of an html 5 output "o" in the example code below  to red if it is negative and green if it is positive?

form oninput="o.value = a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber" 
 input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" + 
 input name="b" id="b" type="number" step="any" = 
 output name="o" for="a b">

/form

Comment: You need to post your JS code first.

Comment: You can set a class to the element using JS, to determine whether the value is positive or negative. Style those classes via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big fan of just giving answers when users haven't shown what they've tried first but this was actually a bit fun, I've never seen this type of form before.

Like @feeela said, you can use JS to watch for input changes and validate the output field accordingly. I'm using jQuery to do this as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(
        function()
        {
            $('output').removeAttr('class');
            var sum = parseInt($('output').first().html());
            if (isNaN(sum))
            {
                $('output').addClass('error');
            }
            else if (sum < 0)
            {
                $('output').addClass('negative');
            }
            else if (sum > 0)
            {
                $('output').addClass('positive');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Then you can use you style sheet to give the output field a colour depending on its class.
    ​
You can view a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/S7cVP/